# How to fix, Element <option> could not be scrolled into view error python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Screenshot of the webpage in the link below:

[image: webpage]

I'm trying to select an option tag in the select element but I'm getting an error message saying element cannot be scrolled into view.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
```

**Code:**

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("motes"))
dropdown.select_by_value("ALDERSHOT [Aldershot]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("motes"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("ALDERSHOT [Aldershot]")
```

There are three methods available to select an option from drop down.

- dropdown.**select_by_index(1)** - Uses index of the option, starts from 1
- dropdown.**select_by_value("")** - Uses value of the option i.e. text of 
  html attribute 'value'
- dropdown.**select_by_visible_text("")** - Uses       visible text

For example, if you want to select "ACOMB - ELEC [York Acomb]"

```
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("motes"))
dropdown.select_by_index(4)
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("ACOMB - ELEC [York Acomb]")
dropdown.select_by_value("433372-#42454c")
```

Note: Value of ALDERSHOT [Aldershot] option is hidden in screenshot hence used alternative.

Comment: Already tried that, but I get the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)